# Software to file handling operations

Tags: filemanager, batch-rename

Is there some tool to Ubuntu like [Filerfrog](http://www.filerfrog.com/features.html), capable to perform tasks like:

- Delete Empty Files\Folders
- Copy Path to Clipboard
- Invert selection
- Split and Join folders
- List of Files inside a folder
- Rename Operations to all files inside specific folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete all empty subfolders, you can use the find command:

```
find -type d -empty  -delete
```

-type d means to only search for directories, -empty and -delete are self explanatory.

To copy the path of the current folder in the Nautilus filemanager to clipboard, simply right click on the folder name in the toolbar and select copy. If you want to display the current directory on the command line, the pwd command does this.

To invert the selection in Nautilus, use the "invert selection" option in the menu (depending on your Nautilus version it might be in the edit menu, or in the general one).

There is also an option to select by pattern, it can be accessed by pressing CTRL+s.

I have no idea, what you mean by "split and join folders".

To list the files inside a folder, you can use the ls command in terminal.

To bulk rename, you can either install a tool like Thunar file manager, or use the command line. Since there are many possible kinds of bulk rename, I can't give a general command line solution, I can just recommend to learn the basics of bash scripting and also to have a look at sed and awk. Believe me, if you have a lot of different file operations to do, it pays of.

Comment: It was not exactly what I'm looking for, but tks for show me some alternatives!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, and I hope, not. You can easily do it all from Terminal.

```
find ./ -size -1c -delete
```

does the first.`rename` command does the last. `man rename` to the rescue. And I didn't get what all other mean, you can do it in *Files* easily.

Comment: Commands are not always the easy way to do things. It is possible to do the same things of Filerfrog on the DOS prompt, but that simple software turn the life of non-expert users easy.